# Как сделать проверку на JSON?

Tags: javascript

Увидел такое

```
if (value[0] == "{")
```

Мне этот вариант не очень нравится.Есть еще способа?
Вот ,что я сам надумал :делать проверку через объект

```
typeof(JSON.parse(value))=='object'.
```

Так подойдет?

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы хотите сделать. JSON - это представление объекта в виде строки. Дополните примером, что вы подаете на вход функции и что должно быть на выходе.

Comment: Скажу так:проверить что переменная является JSON строкой.
Я понятней объяснить не могу.

Comment: А почему вообще вам приходится такое проверять? У вас проблемы с архитектурой. Когда вы получаете строку, вы должны уже знать, в каком она формате, а не сами выяснять.

Comment: я узнал на будущее.Реально с такой задачей не сталкивался.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот такой же [вопрос на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try). Два варианта решения, через JSON.parse()

```
function IsJsonString(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

и через регулярку:

```
if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(text.replace(/\\["\\\/bfnrtu]/g, '@').
replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ''))) {

  //the json is ok

}else{

  //the json is not ok

}
```

Comment: try..catch отличный вариант.Спасибо

Comment: try/catch решает, а эмулировать парсер регуляркой на этом сайте умеет только @ReinRaus.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю вот такую функцию парсера, которую я обычно использую. Она решает проблему с IE

```
function parseJSON(parJSON)
{
    //если переданный параметр - строка (а то мало ли)
    if(typeof parJSON == "string"){
        //начинаем парсит JSON
        return window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ? JSON.parse(parJSON) : eval('('+parJSON+')'); 
        //если браузер поддерживает встроенный JSON, то используем его. Если нет (IE6-7) то используем eval
    }
    return parJSON;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.Куски вашего кода будут полезны.

Answer (score 0):

"А почему вообще вам приходится такое проверять? У вас проблемы с архитектурой. Когда вы получаете строку, вы должны уже знать, в каком она формате, а не сами выяснять.

Могу привести пример из практики.
С qr-code приходит json.
Так вот пользователь может создать свой qr-code и на вход подать не json.
Поэтому!Проблема актуальная и нельзя сразу делать вывод об архитектуре проекта.

Comment: @maxSLON да нет, все правильно. Приложение должно читать json, если приходит не json - просто прерывать выполнение.